# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: sonarqube

Environment details:

- SonarQube 5.6
- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- Java version: 1.7.0_09

I integrated SonarQube plugin with java maven project like in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

While executing goal: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<url>`

Getting exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project example-java-maven:
>         Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar failed:
>         An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar:
>         java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation:
>         Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
>       [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2

Answer (score 27):

SonarQube 5.6 requires at least Java 8 (see [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)). Note that this is not a just a requirement on the server side, it's also required on the client side where analysis are ran.

Like [agabrys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944847/agabrys) mentioned in his comment, the `Unsupported major.minor` is a classic Java error (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi/11432195#11432195)).

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself. My solution since my code and platform being developed is currently only using Java 7, and cannot use Java 8, I decided to launch the previous release/tag (5.5) with:

See tags here:
[Tags for sonarqube at hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/sonarqube/tags/)

`docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube:5.5`

Comment: IMO, this is inadvisable.  It is better to use a recent version of SonarQube and run it on a recent version of Java; e.g. Java 11.  It is easy to configure SonarQube to analyze code that is built for an older JDK version.  See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/#header-5

Answer (score 1):

You need at least JDK 1.8. Read more about `major.minor` version at: [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/4944847)